# "Invalid legacy scope provided" error when attempting to access a Google API from web app?

Tags: json, rest, google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, zoho

Here's what I'm trying to do:

- **Remotely execute a Google Apps Script function from an online automation service (Zoho Flow, similar in purpose to Zapier.)***
- ***This function that I am remotely executing is to add gmail labels to everyone in an organization.***

In order to do this, I've done the following:

1. Created a service account with domain-wide-delegation in the same GCP project associated with the function that adds gmail labels.
2. Used the [OAuth2 library](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-oauth2) for Google Apps Script to perpetuate JWT authorization for that service account in my script.
3. Verified that function works with service account functionality for all users in a Google oragnization within google apps script
4. Deployed this script as an API Executable to enable remote execution
5. Created authtokens authorized with the mail scope for the Apps Script API (https://mail.google.com/), as well as an additional scope required by the [OAuth2 library](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-oauth2) in my script. This is done in the [google developer playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/), using OAuth2.0 Client ID credentials that are authorized as a part of that same GCP project.
6. Successfully executed the function remotely using the Google Apps Script API with [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/)

Now, in order to actually make this functionality official, I now have to replace postman and the google developer console with the actual client, which is this Zoho Flow platform for api connections and process automation.

In order to make the switch I've done the following;

1. Added the authorized redirect URl for the client (Zoho Flow) under the same credentials that are used for the Google Developer Playground:

[image]

2. Utilized the credentials found from the JSON representation of those credentials** for creating what's called a "connection" in this software, which is basically an easy-to-use OAuth2.0 connection with a nice front-end that can be used for accessing API data (this is the part where I create this connection):
   [image]
3. Entered the same scope for this connection that were authorized in the [google developer playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/), as well as that additional scope (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request) that the OAuth2.0 library for Google Apps Script uses:
   [image]

Lo and behold, I get the error below when attempting to gain access to Google API data from a web application, and the scopes that are said to cause the error is every scope ***except*** for the mail scope: https://mail.google.com/. I've done additional testing to verify that every other scope that is a part of the google apps script API also create this error, not just this external scope for the OAuth2 library.

[image]

Support said it was likely an issue with my credential permissions; is my line of logic for this correct? If it is, then it is an issue with their software that I will have them pursue further.

Comment: What scopes are you requesting? Your screenshot is cut short.

Comment: Just the two mentioned there, that's all. That is the case for both the developer console and the zoho flow example.

Comment: The screenshot for the scopes is cut off so I cannot actually read the second scope.

Comment: Have you created a project in the [Google Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/getting-started)? this will allow you to create the credentials and activate the scopes. [This article](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) has an example on how to do it.

Comment: Yes; the Google Cloud Console has a project from which the credentials are referenced both in the Google Developer Playground and the new Client.

Comment: John Hanley: I've updated the question with the full second scope as a part of the text, as the front end doesn't allow the viewing of all scopes fully. That second scope is also copied here: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request

Answer (score 0):

Some additional testing has been done on the software (Zoho Flow) to confirm whether or not it is a software error or not: I'm not certain if the process defined in my answer is best practices, or even 100% correct (other users can speak to it,) but I've confirmed that the error I am seeing is **likely an error with the client.**

**Here's why:**

When authorizing for multiple scopes, I get the error seen at the end of my question:
[image]

When changing that connection to utilize only one of my scopes instead, like so:

[image]

The connection proceeds properly, and I can remotely execute functions that utilize only that one scope successfully. This does work for any one scope that I authorize. The only problem is, it's a rare occurrence that a script only requires one scope. While this I can get around this major bug, I cannot remotely execute my function that adds gmail labels to all users in an organization because it requires two scopes. This will be mentioned to the development team and it should be fixed soon.

Comment: I suggest you open a bug with [Google Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com), explain everything in detail and use the screenshots you have provided. this does seem to be a bug that should be addressed.